# Need to Roll Parent Quantities to Calculate Total Quantity

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, parent-child

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide. I have spent hours on this with no luck.

I'm working with an indented bill of material table which has an end part id, a sequence number, a level and a quantity. The goal is to determine the total cumulative quantity of each row on this table.

What makes this difficult is that to determine the total quantity, the child quantity needs to be multiplied by it's parent quantity. The parent quantity of that parent needs to be multiplied by it's parent quantity and so on.

For example, a level 3 part has a component quantity of 5. It's parent the level 2 part has a component quantity of 2. It's parent the level 1 part has a component quantity of 3. This means the level 3 part total quantity is 30 (3 X 2 X 5).

With the assistance of SO (specifically @KKK) the parent quantity was able to be calculated in the below query. After this was resolved I realized I now need two additional columns, one that shows the Rolled/Cumulative quantities of the parent rows and one that shows the total quantity of the child.

The attached screenshot has the two columns that need to be added highlighted in yellow.  Here is the current SQL (using Oracle 10.2) for the columns that are not in yellow:

```
select 
    end_part_id, sort_seq_no, indented_lvl, comp_qty,
    (select distinct first_value(a.comp_qty) over (order by a.sort_seq_no desc, TRIM(a.indented_lvl) desc)
from 
    report_table a
where  
    a.end_part_id = b.end_part_id
    and a.sort_seq_no < b.sort_seq_no
    and TRIM(a.indented_lvl) < TRIM(b.indented_lvl)) as "PARENT_QTY"
from report_table b
```

[Expected Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hloyA.png)

```
END_PART_ID SORT_SEQ_NO INDENTED_LVL    COMP_QTY    PARENT_QTY  ROLLED_PARENT QTY   TOTAL_QTY
PARTX       1           1                   2       1           1                   2
PARTX       2            2                  5       2           2                   10
PARTX       3             3                 2       5           10                  20
PARTX       4              4                1       2           20                  20
PARTX       5               5               1       1           20                  20
PARTX       6                6              1       1           20                  20
PARTX       7               5               4       1           20                  80
PARTX       8                6              1       4           80                  80
PARTX       9            2                  7       2           2                   14
PARTX       10            3                 2       7           14                  28
PARTX       11            3                 2       7           14                  28
PARTX       12             4                1       2           28                  28
PARTX       13             4                1       2           28                  28
PARTX       14            3                 8       7           14                  112
PARTX       15          1                   1       1           1                   1
PARTX       16           2                  7       1           1                   7
PARTX       17            3                 2       7           7                   14
PARTX       18            3                 2       7           7                   14
PARTX       19             4                1       2           14                  14
PARTX       20             4                1       2           14                  14
```

Comment: You need to post some sample data and expected output.

Comment: Hi @paparazzo, if you click on the 'Table Example' link you can see  the sample data.  This is my second post so they won't let me embed the image in the write-up.

Comment: You can post text data and expected output.

Comment: Can you please provide the steps of how to post the example data?  When I paste it into the message the format isn't clean and I can't see a way to add a table.

Comment: Need to start with format as code.   Please inert necessary spaces.

Comment: Data set has been added.  Thanks!